# Alpha access to instance group method

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I need to create one new instance in a Managed Instance Group in Google Cloud. But I want to set the name on creation, there is a new function in the SDK to do that - but that is an Alpha-function.

How can our Google Cloud project get access to that function? The function where we need access is this one:

```
gcloud alpha compute instance-groups managed create-instance
```

When I try to invoke it with parameters, I get this error:

```
Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'
```

Comment: Just FYI, This feature should now be available in public Beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to this API requires "whitelisting" your Project and/or your Google IAM member ID.

This is an **invitation-only** early access feature. If you have a contact on the Google Cloud Compute Engine team ask for the link to request access. This also requires signing a Google NDA. Approval is on a case-by-case basis and can sometimes take weeks to be approved.

Otherwise you will have to wait until this feature reaches beta status.

Stackoverflow cannot help you with these features. You cannot post questions about these features once you are approved per the NDA. You will receive an email address to send questions to for alpha features and further information.